# Killing Multiple Processes

Tags: c#

How would you go about killing several processes? I'm trying to update a program but I am finding I have to taskkill 8 processes that are related to the main program before I can actually update it. I just want a simple c# program I can run that will kill these so I can do the update.
I know I can do:

```
foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("program-1"))

        {
            process.Kill();
        }
```

But when I try to add "program-1","program-2","program-3",etc I get errors.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use Process.GetProcesses() and filter the processes you want to kill:

```
await Process.GetProcesses()
             .Where(p => p.ProcessName.ToLower()
                                      .StartsWith("program-"))
             .ToAsyncEnumerable()
             .ForEachAsync(p => p.Kill());
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to `@Majid Shahabfar` answer:

[Kill(Boolean)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.kill?view=net-5.0) stops the process and its child/descendent processes.

Further more, `Kill` is an async method and a good practice after calling `Kill()` is to wait for the process to exit using [WaitForExit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit?view=net-5.0) method, or calling [HasExited](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.hasexited?view=net-5.0)  to ensure the process has exited.